# Linear motion in the equatorial frame

Tags: orbit, observational-astronomy

I would like to calculate how the RA/Dec changes when an object has an apparent linear motionin the equatorial sphere. For example, more or less what an artificial satellite would do in a circular orbit.

In particular, what I'm looking for is as follows:

I have the RA/dec of the object at two times, *t1*, and *t2*. Assuming it has a linear motion at constant speed, what RA/dec will it have a *t3*? So it will have an angular separation proportional to the one it had between *t1* and *t2*, and the three points will form a straight line.

Comment: This appears to be a simple spherical coordinates math problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: @barrycarter no, you are not missing anything. I did not know how to search for the formula in the internet even assuming that it looked like a very simple problem. I later found the formula (for Earth surface motion using lat/long but it is the same problem). Thank you,

Comment: @siritinga If you solved your problem, you can post an answer to your own question, in case someone else with the same problem finds this post in the future.